# Converting a column variable in a table from Numeric Year to Date Year (01-01-2021)

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame which has two columns, one is called `year` and is in a `numeric integer form` e.g. 1990 etc... I want to convert this into a date e.g. `01-01-1990` etc... I'm thinking I should be able to use `parse_date` or similar but can't work it out.

Comment: Could you also mention the language that you're trying it in? And Show what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry new to this. I am using R. My data frame as two cols which the first one is Year. I want to change the year column from being an integer to a date. So the date will be (year, day, month). I only have a year number so for example 1996 would mutate to be year-day-month like 1996-01-01. I am trying make_date

Comment: so for example   datatable %>% mutate(year = make_date(year)) i get this error Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `year`.
i `year = make_date(year)`.
x cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'integer'
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: The year colum is saying its is type integer but the error is suggesting some issue with closure?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.